# Hexadecimal representation of tenths place of $\frac{A}{C}$

Tags: number-theory

So we can write $$\frac{A}{C}= a_1 \times 10^{-1} + a_2 \times 10^{-2} + a_3 \times 10^{-3} +\cdots$$ How do I find the hexadecimal representation of $a_1$ where all numbers and variables are in the base $16$? I think it would just be $a_1$ itself since decimal numbers less than $10$ are equivalent to the hexadecimal numbers. Am I right?

Comment: Why would you want to know the hexadecimal representation of $a_1$? What purpose could that possibly serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the hexadecimal representation of the "tenths" digit, then yes it would be literally $a_1$. For instance, in $0.5$, the hexadecimal representation of $5$ is $5$.

However, this is not the same as saying that the hexadecimal representation of $\frac{A}{C}$ has the digit $a_1$ right after the point. For example, $0.5_{\text{dec}}\neq 0.5_{\text{hex}}$, since $0.5_{\text{dec}}=0.8_{\text{hex}}$. For another example, $0.25_{\text{dec}}=0.4_{\text{hex}}$. The first digit after the point in hexadecimal is the sixteenths place, so determining what digit it will be based on the decimal representation is somewhat more complicated than your original proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to convert the decimal fraction representing the first 9 digits of the fractional portion of the Archimedes number $\pi$  to its hexadecimal equivalent.
0.141592654
Multiply the fraction by 16. Each time you do this, you are creating an integer to the west of the decimal point whose value is in the range of -- a hexadecimal digit!
2.265482464
Strip the integral portion of the result (2), convert it to its hexadecimal form. This will be the first digit of the result.
.2
0.265482464
Multiply again by 16.
4.247719424
Strip the integral portion of the result (4), convert it to its hexadecimal form. This will be the second digit of the result.
.24
0.247719424
Repeat this process five more times. At this point, you will have seven hexadecimal digits.
0.243F6A8
Why do we stop at seven hexadecimal digits? Well, we started with nine decimal digits; in general, $n$ decimal digits can be represented with ${\frac{\ln{10}}{\ln{16}}}·n$ hexadecimal digits, or seven in this case. More digits than the length of the decimal input can justify would not add to, and more likely would detract from, the correctness of the result.